# I need to change Div Eliment's color according to the text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the span color according to the contents inside the span tag for example red, green, blue, yellow, I could not use nth-child nor inline class. due to cms restriction. I hope it could be possible with only css, if not possible then what is the appropriate method?

Thanks in advance

```
.selected-color span.value{
    color:grey;
}
```

```css
.selected-color .value{
      color:grey; /*default color*/
}
```

```html
<div class="selected-color">
    <div class="value">red</div>
    <div class="value">green</div>
    <div class="value">blue</div>
    <div class="value">yellow</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the elements with `.each()` in jquery and take current object `$(this)` and apply css color for all elements through jquery

```
$(".selected-color .value ").each(function() {

      var value=  $(this).text();
      $(this).css("color", value);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4ar2mcq/)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with jQuery. Iterate over .value elements, get each text value and assign ass css property `color`

```js
$('.value').each(function () {
  var val = $(this).text();
  $(this).css({'color':val});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selected-color">
        <div class="value">red</div>
        <div class="value">green</div>
        <div class="value">blue</div>
        <div class="value">yellow</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".selected-color .value ").each(function() {
     //If any leading or trailing space then remove it
      var value=  $(this).text().trim();
      $(this).css("color", value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selected-color">
    <div class="value">red</div>
    <div class="value">green</div>
    <div class="value">blue</div>
    <div class="value">yellow</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use jQuery for this, as pure CSS doesn't know about the content of your divs.

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".value").each(function( index ) {
        $(this).css("color", $(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

(Don't forget to load jQuery library to your website, if you haven't already).

And working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw6Ljkcj/).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to reference directly to the content via CSS. You can only point to tags. If you have a tag, you can set a class or refer to an attribute or similar but never to direct content (at least, as I know).

So, you must "repeat" in your case the content as a value inside the class like below.

```css
.selected-color > .value.red { color: red; }
.selected-color > .value.green { color: green; }
.selected-color > .value.blue { color: blue; }
.selected-color > .value.yellow { color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="selected-color">
    <div class="value red">red</div>
    <div class="value green">green</div>
    <div class="value blue">blue</div>
    <div class="value yellow">yellow</div>
</div>
```